# Systematic approach to Weierstrass factorization

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, factorization

If you want to calculate the Taylor expansion of a function, you only need to know the derivatives of the function at the point of expansion.

Is there a similar algorithmic approach that can be implemented, from which the Weierstrass factorization of the function can be obtained, provided that the zeros are known?

Is there a general approach available at all? How can you find out the exponentials that are required for convergence?

Comment: As explained [on the Wikipedia page about  the product expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem), we need to know some thing about the rate at which $|a_n|$ grow. Once we know that an explicit formula is given on that page. The expression, unlike the Taylor expansion, is not unique.

Comment: If zeros "are known" then their exponent of convergence is also "known" :-) Speaking of the exponential factor, its coefficients are simply related to the Taylor series at $0$.  So if the genus is finite, and you know zeros, there is no problem.